# Sitemap - Wordpress site on subdomain

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, subdomain, sitemap

I'm trying to get a definite answer regarding the issue. I have an html website which contains a `WordPress` blog under it in a subdomain as a folder.

I currently have site map on both the html site and the blog itself. Is that the way to go ? I have also noticed that the sitemap on the html site doesn't include any of my `pages/posts` from the blog, should it include them as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the methode said, this is perfectly fine and acceptable.  All you have to do is just add the in your robots.txt file so that search engines can crawl your html site as well as blog.

First of all create a new robots.txt (if not created earlier) in root / home /www foler of your website and add the following two lines by replacing them with your site related values

```
sitemap: http://<www.yoursite.com>/<path_to_your_html_sitemap>.xml

sitemap: http://<www.yoursite.com>/<path_to_your_blog_sitemap>.xml
```

Comment: Normally you should have a robots.txt file for the main site and another one for the blog, which is on a separate sub-domain. 

And it's normal that your main site's sitemap won't contain links to a blog that's on a separate sub-domain. The sub-domain is meant to be treated as a separate purpose-built site, capable of functioning on its own.

Comment: yes FarhadD i agree with you. if you want to treat your sub-domain as a separate purpose built site you have to place two separate robots.txt for each domain/sub-domain. but if main domain and sub-domain are inter-related then a single robots.txt can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Having two sitemaps for the root and subdomain is perfectly fine and acceptable. Don't forget to submit them to search engines, or include them in your `robots.txt` file if you have one.